# How casting of generics works Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

If I declare a list "myList" that I happen to know will only contain strings I can cast it to a List without any problems, what is actually going on behind the scenes to cast the list to a list of strings?

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
List<String> myStringList = (List<String>) myList;
```

If I create the list as list of objects I would assume that the same thing applies but I can no longer cast this back to a list of strings, what is the reason for this?

```
List<Object> myObjList = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<String> myStringList = (List<String>) myObjList; // Can't do this!
```

Comment: It would probably help if you added sample code

Comment: Remember, generics are supposed to provide *guarantees* that your code is type-safe. Your second example won't allow type-safe code, so it isn't allowed. The first code sample involves raw types which skip these checks altogether.

Answer (score 1):

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
List<String> myStringList = (List<String>) myList;
```

Works for compatibility reasons with pre-generics code. It works, but it can give you errors at runtime if the raw `List` contains not only `Strings`.

Generics are supposed to protect you at compiler time. They don't let you cast a `list of Objects` into a `list of String`, because the `List<Objects>` could contain objects that are not `String` and it would result in errors at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are Objects but Objects are not Strings, that is why you can't do the second code.

I like to think of it like this: A dog is an animal and can behave like an animal but an animal is not a dog.

Good info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: very much like the a square is a rectangle but a rectangle is not a square.

Comment: Might want to add in explanations for the first snippet too

Comment: Why and how am I able to do the first one then as I could have a heap of Integers in there for all it knows?

Comment: @user2248702 Look up "raw types"

Comment: But `Object` can be `String` and `Animal` can be a `Dog` right ?

Comment: @ViswanathL An Object can be of type String and an Animal can be of type Dog, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Technically adding a clause to answer by `@FunctionR`

```
Strings are Objects but Objects are not Strings
```

But `Objects` can be `String`

`Object` is a base class of `String`. So you can do cast on both direction.

For example,

```
Object a = null;
String s = "";

a = s;
s = (String)a;
```

So `String` can be a `Object`.

But in `List<Object>` and `List<String>`

You should do this

```
List<Object> myObjList = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<String> myStringList = (List) myObjList;
```

Comment: Well, more like you *can*. You really *shouldn't*, though. Doing that is asking for a *lot* of trouble.

Comment: Yeah, if `ArrayList<Object>` contains other objects than `String`, then casting it into `List<String>` and accessing it can result in exceptions at runtime. And if `ArrayList<Object>` is supposed to hold only `Strings` then is should be declared as `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Yes but the question does sounds only getting the way to do it, right. Casting `Objects` can give you error at any time unless you know the type exactly.

Comment: @Viswanath L Yes, but it is not the same. Casting `Object` into wrong type will result in an exception in this exact place. And casting raw `List` into generic `List` will result in an exception in some other place, during retrieving the element with wrong type from the generic `List`, so it may be harder to localize the source of the error.